# how to reduce web page size with many select controls

Tags: asp.net, optimization, select, listbox

I'm working on an asp.net application that allows the user to update data for a series of days.  The data is presented as a table:

> Date -       Active -    Active Promotion
>
> 04/11/11 - yes - listbox with 360 entries
>
> 05/11/11-   yes   -     listbox with 360 entries
>
> 06/11/11 -  yes   -     listbox with 360 entries
>
> ...
>
> 04/02/12 -   yes - listbox with 360 entries

Now, the table can have from 90-700 rows (eg allow entry for 90-700 days) and the select box has 360 entries (12,000 characters).  So, for a 3 month display, I get the page size of 90 * 12,000 = 1MB and this increases to 8.4MB for a 2 year display.

I can see that the problem is the many repeated listbox .  I have thought of the following approaches, perhaps people can suggest improvements or refinements:

- Have each listbox populate itself when clicked (reduces initial page size but user may have to wait for drop down to populate)
- Have one 'real' listbox and many 'fake' listbox .  when the user clicks on a 'fake' listbox the 'real' listbox is then displayed, the selected value is then stored in a hidden field
- get the client to cleanup the data so there aren't 300+ options in each box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the options are the same for every listbox, I would definitely suggest auto-populate with javascript on clicking.  I've used this solution before for exactly the same reason, and there is no perceptible delay in popping up the select list, and the original page loads way faster.

Also Firefox used to have a bug when handling lots of large select elements, and the javascript populate when necessary solution also sidestepped that.

Comment: hmm, javascript would definitely be better than ajax for each call.  this is also an intranet site, that only support IE8, so (thankfully) I don't have to worry about other browsers.

Comment: Not quite - AJAX is a subset of javascript, in this context it would suggest sending a request to the server to ask for the list of options for the select element.  That would introduce a noticeable delay.  My suggestion would be to supply the option list on a single dummy select element, and copy the option list to any clicked select element.  From experience, this will be very quick on most browsers, to the point of not being noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like the second option. What you can also do is to populate the first one initially, and then copy the contents to others using JavaScript.

But otherwise - seems you got some usability problems to solve, who's gonna use such monster forms!? :)

Comment: i agree with you on the monster forms, but this is an intranet site and the small set of users seem generally accepting of the monster forms.  they find it 'easy' to update two years of data at one time.

Comment: Ah, the benefits of plain users. :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would limit input to one month at a time and store it in memory until ready to complete the transaction back to the DB. I would also review choice of control for this, that is, instead of a listbox think of something more intuitive; possibly a calendar with text boxes - you could use tabs and move from one month to the next.